# How to match all rows in one colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have this table

Availabilty

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
id|    date    |count
---------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 15-05-2018 |1
2 | 15-05-2019 |1
3 | 15-05-2020 |1
4 | 15-05-2021 |1
```

I want to get All count records if and only if they exist in all dates i pass,
for example. 
if i passed days `15-05-2018` and `15-05-2019` i get those counts 
if i passed days `15-05-2018` and `14-05-2018` it should return nothing

i tried to write query something like

```
select Availabilty.count from Availabilty where Availabilty.date between ? and ?
```

but this will return a record even if it is exist one time i need to match all days. how can i achieve this

I hope my question is well understood by you.

Comment: Store dates as dates. Then get back to us.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's not going to work

Comment: And how does 'between' make any sense in the context of this question!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of matching records and compare to the number of dates in the period.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
select a.count
from Availabilty a
where a.date between ? and ? and
      (select count(*)
       from Availability a2
       where a2.date between ? and ?
      ) = datediff(?, ?) + 1;
```

Hmmm.  In your problem, you should not be using `between`.  I think you want:

```
select a.count
from Availabilty a
where a.date in (<list>) and
      (select count(*)
       from Availability a2
       where a2.date a.date in (<list>)
      ) = <n>;
```